# Fancybox detect from Inside

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Let me explain the situation.

Website A: www.mywebsitea.com
Website B: www.mywebsiteb.com

Website A ist hosting the Fancybox.
Website B is hosting the content opended in the Fancybox of A.

I have to find out from the Website B if my content is Opened in the fancybox of A or not.

How can i do that?
I've tried multiple solution, but they doesn't work.

One of this solution was:

```
  try {
     if(!(parent.$ && parent.$.fancybox))
     {
        window.location = "http://mylink.com"
     }
  }
  catch(e){
  }
```

Has someone a other solution?

Thanks for the help.
Adrian

Comment: Is the iFrame empty to begin with? or do the links change all the time and you need to make sure the link followed through? Or are you trying to monitor for server errors, like 404?

Comment: The iFrame is not Empty.. I start with one link. The link changes during the navigation. You can have a look at the website. www.gstaad.ch -> On the top of the website click Livecam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reach parent variables except is in same domain. See: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Bu you can check is in a iframe with

```
var isInIframe = self != top;
```

If is in a iframe then and you can't reach top window, that means some site showing your website in a iframe.

Comment: +1 my answer should consider "same origin policy" as pointed out by @arunes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if `Site B` was opened from `Site A` within an `iframe`, then inside of `Site B` have this script

```
if(parent.window.location.href =="http://www.mywebsitea.com"){
 alert('opened from Site A')
}
```

On the other hand, if you just want to know if `Site B` was opened from anywhere (including `Site A`) but within fancybox, then inside of `Site B` have this script

```
if(parent.jQuery().fancybox) {
 alert("opened inside of fancybox")
}
```